# Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

I'am getting this:

```
Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!
```

when trying to run Joomla 3.1.1 on PHP 5.2...

My webspace provider could not make any php(5.3) upgrade at the moment.

I add

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

to my htacess.txt file but nothing

How can i run joomla 3 on php 5.2?

Comment: I believe you answered your own question in the question.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: To be honest, you should do yourself a favour and change host. A decent hosting company should always provide upgrade options at any time. PHP 5.2 is not supported anymore and thus your host should not have it on their servers. I had the same problem with hostgator on a reseller account and they said I had to make all these changes for every account. I thought "balls to that" so moved to another, more reliable host

Comment: If changing host is out of the question, then you can always use Joomla 2.5 which is the long term release and compatible with PHP 5.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't run it on PHP 5.2.

But what you can do it find a better host that keeps PHP updated.

Answer (score 4):

Joomla 3.x requires PHP 5.3.1 or higher to work properly but **if your host offers an updated version of PHP**, you can easily override the default PHP version with an htaccess rule.

The filename should be `.htaccess`.

- Connect to your site with FTP or File Manager
- Create a file named htaccess.txt
- Paste the following line into it:

Code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

- Rename it to `.htaccess`.

If it doesn't work, you might want to change `register_globals` in your php.ini to `off`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `Joomla requires PHP 5.3.1 or higher to work properly` >> not all versions. 3.x requires it but 2.5 can happily run on PHP 5.2

Comment: I didn't look at the latest Joomla COde, but I believe register_globals is not the key setting here. What if the host doesn't have a > 5.3 version installed?

Comment: I do not have access on register_globals

Comment: Using `AddType` will only work if the host has added the type. Most hosts don't do this.

Comment: @FestusTamakloe: perhaps talk to your hosting support or move to a different hosting?

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks for your suggestion. I'll to with them

Answer (score 3):

You cant, it most likely uses 5.3 specific features so what you are asking is impossible. YOu need to upgrade to 5.3

Answer (score 3):

Joomla requires 5.3 or higher because it's accessing features not found in older versions of PHP.  It's not an issue of merely trying to pretend you have 5.3 or lying to Joomla.

Some webhosts might actually have a newer PHP installed, but it's not using it by default.  If you search the help there might be a trick to enable 5.3 or newer on your site.  If your host isn't offering 5.3 at all, it's time to find a new host.  And while you are looking for a new host, get one that's running a recent build of 5.4.x because even 5.3 is now considered old.

Comment: `Joomla requires PHP 5.3.1 or higher` >> not all versions. 3.x requires it but 2.5 can happily run on PHP 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Your htaccess file name should be `.htaccess` not `htaccess.txt`

Secondly, your host has to have that application type registered.

Comment: Get a different version of Joomla or a new web host.

Comment: That doesn't solve his issue. His host already said they don't support 5.3.